# How to find the units of the rate constant?

Tags: kinetics, units

> Consider the reaction $$\ce{2A + B -> Products},$$ when the concentration of $\ce{B}$ alone was doubled, the half-life did not change. When the concentration of $\ce{A}$ alone was doubled, the rate increased by two times. The units of the rate constant is:
>
> a) $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$
>
> b) $\mathrm{L\ mol^{-1}\ s^{-1}}$
>
> c) Unitless
>
> d) $\mathrm{mol\ L^{-1}\ s^{-1}}$

I have tried it solving through this method:

According to me, when the concentration of $\ce{A}$ alone was doubled, reaction rate also increased by two time, implies that reaction is first order according to $\ce{A}$. In same way, the reaction should be 0th order according to $\ce{B}$. So the net order would be 1. So this gives me answer $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$ but the answer is $\mathrm{L\ mol^{-1}\ s^{-1}}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Martin  If the reaction were zero order in B and first order in A, it would be first order overall and have a half-life. If the reaction is first order in B and first order in A, it would not have a half-life (or in other words, the half-life would be concentration dependent) unless it is pseudo-first order because A is much more concentrated than B. I don't think the question makes sense.

Comment: @Karsten I'm not sure how I can help you here. I've just added some markup and removed the homework tag. Have I introduced an error in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in situation **when concentration of B alone was doubled but half life did not change.**

In this situation, the reaction order should be 1 according to B as Half life in first order reaction doesn't depend upon initial concentration of reactants.

$$t_{1/2} = \ln2 / k $$

So the final order will be $2$ and the answer of the question will be b.

Comment: @orthocresol But if it is first order in B and first order in A, the integrated rate law (starting with equal concentrations of A and B) would not be an exponential function with a half-life.

Comment: @KarstenTheis, thank you, I do see your point, but my only edit was to change $K$ to $k$. I was too lazy to check for factual correctness. Please feel free to edit as you wish... (or provide your own answer if you prefer...)